# How to save card details (payment method) in Stripe using backend?

Tags: stripe-payments

The [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse-cards-only?platform=web) only covers the case where the payment method is created by the frontend (JS). But there is a risk that the user leaves the website before the frontend sends the information to the backend that the card has been added (and its ID).

In order to make a payment, I need ID of the payment method. I don't want to query Stripe's API for user cards IDs every time before making a payment, so I want to save the payment method ID in my local database. I also want to allow the user to define more payment methods and choose the default one.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are using the non-recommended workflow you linked to? The most up-to-date version can be found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse)

Have you checked out using [webhook listeners](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)?  I use them to create/update my local records.

In the workflow you reference, 3 webhook events potentially fire. First the `setup_intent.created` event is triggered when your server code generates the SetupIntent and its `client_secret`.  Then, when the user fills out whatever Payment or Card element you instantiate and your frontend code calls the `stripe.confirmCardSetup()` (or `stripe.confirmSetup()` in the case of a PaymentElement), both the `setup_intent.succeeded` and `payment_method.attached` events will fire.

This last one will POST the `payment_method` object that was just attached to your customer back to your system.  This object will have both the Payment Method ID as well as the associated Customer ID.  You can use these to update your local records to map payment methods to customers in your server and avoid unnecessary API calls.